# How to split and dispatch an async control-flow using Continuations?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, continuations

I have an asynchronous control-flow like the following:

```
ActorA ! DoA(dataA, callback1, callbackOnErrorA)

def callback1() = {
  ...
  ActorB ! DoB(dataB, callback2, callbackOnErrorB)
}

def callback2() = {
  ActorC ! DoC(dataC, callback3, callbackOnErrorC)
} 

...
```

How would I divide this flow into several parts (continuations) and sequentially dispatch these to different actors (or threads/tasks) while maintaining the overall state?

Any hint appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very simplified, but shows how to split up a single control flow among three actors, passing the state along to each:

```
package blevins.example

import scala.continuations._
import scala.continuations.ControlContext._
import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.actors._

object App extends Application {

  val actorA, actorB, actorC = actor {
    receive {
      case f: Function1[Unit,Unit] => { f() }
    }
  }

  def handle(a: Actor) = shift { k: (Unit=>Unit) =>
    a ! k
  }

  // Control flow to split up
  reset {
      // this is not handled by any actor
      var x = 1
      println("a: " + x)

      handle(actorA)  // actorA handles the below
      x += 4
      println("b: " + x)

      handle(actorB) // then, actorB handles the rest
      var y = 2
      x += 2
      println("c: " + x)

      handle(actorC) // and so on...
      y += 1
      println("d: " + x + ":" + y)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

I like to use `scalaz.concurrent.Promise`. This example isn't exactly like the one in your question, but it gives you the idea.

```
object Async extends Application {
  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._
  import concurrent._
  import concurrent.strategy._
  import java.util.concurrent.{ExecutorService, Executors}

  case class ResultA(resultb: ResultB, resulta: ResultC)
  case class ResultB()
  case class ResultC()

  run

  def run {
    implicit val executor: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8)
    import Executor.strategy

    val promiseA = doA
    println("waiting for results")
    val a: ResultA = promiseA.get
    println("got " + a)
    executor.shutdown    
  }

  def doA(implicit s: Strategy[Unit]): Promise[ResultA] = {
    println("triggered A")
    val b = doB
    val c = doC
    for {bb <- b; cc <- c} yield ResultA(bb, cc)
  }

  def doB(implicit s: Strategy[Unit]): Promise[ResultB] = {
    println("triggered B")
    promise { Thread.sleep(1000); println("returning B"); ResultB() }
  }

  def doC(implicit s: Strategy[Unit]): Promise[ResultC] = {
    println("triggered C")
    promise { Thread.sleep(1000); println("returning C"); ResultC() }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
triggered A
triggered B
triggered C
waiting for results
returning B
returning C
got ResultA(ResultB(),ResultC())
```

You'll find an introduction to [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) concurrency in this [presentation](http://twitter.com/runarorama/status/8573543228) from Runar.

This approach isn't as flexible as Actors, but composes better and can't deadlock.

Comment: Nice Scalaz Promise-Example, thank you. However I want to get a deeper understanding of the new Scala2.8-CPS thing and would appreciate a CPS-specific answer.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the advantages of Futures over Actors, and the use of implicit vals for defining the strategies.

Answer (score 1):

See [Akka's Futures and how to compose them](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.3/scala/futures.html#composing-futures) or [scalaz's Promises](http://www.slideshare.net/bostonscala/beyond-mere-actors), they are nearly the same, there are only slight differences.