# What is the Scala equivalent of F#'s async workflows?

Tags: scala, f#, async-workflow

What is the Scala equivalent of F#'s async workflows?

For example, how would following F# snippet translate to idiomatic Scala?

```
open System.Net
open Microsoft.FSharp.Control.WebExtensions

let urlList = [ "Microsoft.com", "http://www.microsoft.com/"
                "MSDN", "http://msdn.microsoft.com/"
                "Bing", "http://www.bing.com"
              ]

let fetchAsync(name, url:string) =
    async { 
        try
            let uri = new System.Uri(url)
            let webClient = new WebClient()
            let! html = webClient.AsyncDownloadString(uri)
            printfn "Read %d characters for %s" html.Length name
        with
            | ex -> printfn "%s" (ex.Message);
    }

let runAll() =
    urlList
    |> Seq.map fetchAsync
    |> Async.Parallel 
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore

runAll()
```

Comment: Don't tell anyone but F#'s workflows are just monads in disguise. If Scala has some syntax for monads (I don't speak Scala, so I can't tell), then that's the equivalent.

Comment: that's not totaly true - it's the continuation-monad plus a lot extra stuff for exception handling and usage of the ThreadPool/Tasks, etc. - it's non-trivial to just redo this

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes "Don't tell anyone but F#'s workflows are just monads in disguise". That is not quite correct. *Computation expressions* are the general framework for monadic syntax in F# of which asynchronous workflows are a specific form designed to make non-blocking code more readable.

Comment: @CarstenKönig It's not the continuation Monad (Cont), they're binding mechanisms are different and have completely different signatures. I would rather say it's based on the IO Monad.

Answer (score 6):

You code more or less directly can be translated to Scala using `Futures` (with some important features lost, though):

```
import scala.actors.Futures
import Futures._

val urlList = Map("Microsoft.com" -> "http://www.microsoft.com/",
                "MSDN" -> "http://msdn.microsoft.com/",
                "Bing" -> "http://www.bing.com")


def fetchAsync(name: String, url: String) = future {
    // lengthy operation simulation
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("Fetching from %s: %s" format(name, url))
}

def runAll = 
    //Futures.awaitAll(  <- if you want to synchronously wait for the futures to complete 
    urlList.map{case (name, url) => fetchAsync(name, url)}
    //)
```

Comment: I think the point of F# asynchronous wokflows is that you can easily write code that doesn't block threads (as it uses continuations instead of threads). I'm not that familiar with Scala, but I don't think that futures achieve this - because a future runs on a single thread until it completes, doesn't it?

Comment: @Tomas, you're absolutely right (that's why I mentioned above that some important differences exist). A more direct analogue to F# async would be Akka's Futures implementation (http://doc.akka.io/futures-scala), or promises in Scalaz (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446770/how-to-split-and-dispatch-an-async-control-flow-using-continuations).

Comment: @Tomas A future _is_ a continuation, and any code _must_ be run on a process or thread. At best, one can have async read and write, which is performed by some hardware and then notified to the CPU. That said, futures interact badly with blocking I/O -- because the scheduler won't spawn new threads -- which is a shame.

Comment: @Daniel, I think, the biggest complaint was that in stdlib it's not possible to (easily) put a continuation on a future completion

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral You missed Tomas' point. The scheduler shouldn't have to spawn new threads because the code should not be blocking the threads it already has.

Comment: -1 This translation is completely wrong. The F# is non-blocking and, consequently, scalable. This Scala is not only fully blocking but it is blocking threadpool threads which will deadlock the entire threadpool. The Akka link in your comment looks relevant but its broken.

Comment: @VasilRemeniuk "I think, the biggest complaint was that in stdlib it's not possible to (easily) put a continuation on a future completion". And that's the easy part. The hard part is the automated propagation of exception handlers from one continuation to the next with correct resource cleanup.

Comment: @JonHarrop No, I did not miss Tomas point. What F# Async and what Scala Futures do is exactly the same thing: create tasks representing all the code it has to run, and then running all runnable tasks in an automatically managed pool of threads. Creating a future is not blocking, and there's no 1-to-1 allocation between futures and threads, just like F# Async. The only difference is that I/O on F# async return the thread, while I/O in Scala keeps the thread, unless you explicitly select async I/O. In the absence of I/O, they work just the same.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral "What F# Async and what Scala Futures do is exactly the same thing". That is incorrect. What you describe is called a `Task` on .NET. Note that the F# is non-blocking whereas the Scala is blocking...

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/futures.html is the updated link to the Akka futures documentation.

Comment: @JonHarrop What _exactly_ is blocking in Scala?

Comment: About blocking IO: Current Scala versions have blocking { ... } with a blocking context to tell the scheduler this thread is blocking and the default implementations then adds threads to offset the blocking ones.