# Asynchronous coding in Scala

Tags: scala, web-crawler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Scala equivalent of F#'s async workflows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579602/what-is-the-scala-equivalent-of-fs-async-workflows)

Is there an equivalent to F# async workflows in Scala ? I would like to use this to crawl webpages concurrently.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a task asynchronously in parallel, simply use `Actor.actor` method:

```
import scala.actors.Actor._

actor {
  // code here is excuted asynchronously  
}
```

To execute a task and wait for a result, use futures:

```
import scala.actors.Futures.future

val f = future {
  // code here is excuted asynchronously
  // last expression is returned
}
//... other code
val result = f() // block until f is completed and return the value
```

For more complex workflows, have a look at Scala (or Akka) actors. You can also have a look at java NIO which allows async IO operations.